# Making a Dictionary from an HTML Table through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this table I scraped from eBay that looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/0geoFUv.png and the HTML code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/FNdkqJSn

Basically, from the image above, the output should be something like

```
scraped_table = {'Condition': 'New', 'Brand': 'MyBrand', 'MPN': 'Does not apply', 'UPC': 'Does not apply'}
```

However, the table may have different values (as in, there may not always be a UPC or MPN value set and there may be more values). I am not sure how I can go about scraping this table.

I am able to select the table by finding the 'table' element but how do I loop through the values and put it in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of the table is `<td class="attrLabels"> ...Attribute... </td><td> ...Attribute value... </td>`, you can do this (`txt` is your HTML snippet):

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = {}
for attr, txt in zip(soup.select('td.attrLabels'), soup.select('td.attrLabels + td')):
    out[attr.get_text(strip=True)] = txt.get_text(strip=True).split(':')[0]

# pretty print to screen:
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Brand:': 'MyBrand',
 'Condition:': 'New',
 'MPN:': 'Does Not Apply',
 'UPC:': 'Does not apply'}
```